# How to get details about Stashes in LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Is there some way to get the list of stashes along with their names (and perhaps other info) and then see what files changes and the diffs?

I am using LibGit2Sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Diff** is currently being implemented and should be available as part of the next version (v0.9.0).

- *"Tree to tree"* list of changes is already [available](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/81b1186c4541130f4636b5af9340109a75378986#diff-0).
- *"Index to Workdir"*, *"Blob to blob"* and *"Index to Tree"* should be released in the following days

List of stashed changes is not implemented yet.

**UPDATE:** You could still access the latest stashed changes by directly accessing the reference. Something like this may work:

```
[SkippableFact]
public void CanRetrieveTheLatestStashedChanges()
{
    using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/the/repository"))
    {
        Reference latestStash = repo.Refs["refs/stash"];

        InconclusiveIf(() => latestStash == null, "Nothing has been stashed.");

        var changes = repo.Lookup<Commit>(latestStash.TargetIdentifier);
        Assert.NotNull(changes);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is good to hear. Is there an issue on Github to watch for "Stash support"?

Comment: Not yet. Would you please create one?

Comment: Stash support is currently being implemented. You can watch it [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/352).